# how to make a test on cancel button when using inputbox

Tags: powershell

i'm using this code to make an inputbox

Do {
$label = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Entrez le nom de volume de la clé USB", "Volume", 'PLUS que 0 ET MOINS de 12 caractères')
} until ($label.length -lt 12 -and !($label -eq ""))

But when user clic on cancel button i need script to stop.

is there a way to test when clic on cancel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

Your code is not correct. Well, your logic is not.

What you are using, results to the same thing, hence cancel is never valid, hence the reason the msgbox never closes / redraws.

This..

```
$label = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::
```

... will always contain the result of which button was pressed.

So, this...

```
until (($label.length -lt 12) -or ($label -eq ''))
```

If you want to take a deep look at doing this MsgBox sort of thing then [see this sample script.](http://drews-powershell.blogspot.com/2014/07/popup-menu.html)

Ideally you can look at doing your own WinForm or WPF dialog, which gives you far more control and visual expression. See this module from the [MS powershellgallery.com](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

```
Find-Module -Name AnyBox

Version    Name    Repository           Description                                                                                   
-------    ----    ----------           -----------                                                                                   
0.3.3      AnyBox  PSGallery            Designed to facilitate script input/output with an easily customizable WPF window

Find-Module -Name AnyBox | Save-Module -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Force
Install-Module -Name AnyBox
```